# javascript error implementing 'error' and 'complete' handlers in fine-uploader jquery call

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I am a Java developer, and not a great JS programmer, so maybe I'm just missing something here. But I am getting an error I don't know how to interpret or fix trying to put some custom handling of the 'on complete' and 'on error' logic into the my fine-uploader call.

The actual file uploading part is working, however my custom calls to 'alert' are not.

Here is the script code:

```
            $j(document).ready(function () {
                $j('#uploadNonDICOM_uploader').fineUploader({
                    request: {
                        inputName: 'uploadNonDICOM',
                        endpoint: '/handleUpload?',
                        params: {
                             nav: 'Cases',
                             subnav: 'New Case',
                             action: 'uploadCaseFile',
                             id: function() {return document.getElementById('id').value},
                             timestamp: function() {return document.getElementById('timestamp').value}
                        }
                    }
                }).on('error', function (event, id, name, responseJSON) {
                     alert('file upload failed'); 
                }).on('complete', function (event, id, name, responseJSON) {
                     alert('file uploaded'); 
                });
            });
```

The file uploader is actually working, but I get an error when looking in firebug, and the "alert" calls are not being made.

The error I am getting is:
`TypeError: $j(...).fineUploader(...).on is not a function
http://localhost:8080/SpectraRad?nav=Cases&subnav=New%20Case
Line 741`

Where line 741 is:

```
                }).on('error', function (event, id, name, responseJSON) {
```

To me this indicates I am maybe making a syntactical error?? For the life of me I cant see it if I am.

Any help I can get figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dustin

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.6.1

Comment: .on doesn't exist in 1.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

The `on` method was added to jQuery 1.7.  You are using 1.6.1, which does not include this function.  You can use `bind` in place of `on`.  However, I **strongly** suggest, instead, you use a more recent version of jQuery.

Also, the signature for your `error` handler is incorrect, but that is not the cause of your problem.  Please see the [events page in the documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html) for a description of all parameters passed to each event handler.

Comment: great catch! thank you! proably saved me some banging head against wall syndrome later! I fixed it now to be `(event, id, name, reason)`

Comment: Note that the associated XMLHttpRequest/XDomainRequest transport object instance is also passed to your error handler (as the last param), if available.  Not sure if you need that or not.  In most cases, probably not.

Comment: In my case I don't. Although I did not see that covered in docs here: http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/jquery.html which is what I was going off of.

Comment: I suppose it should be listed there, but it is present on the events documentation page.